# Xamarin give a "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" On using MainPage = new AppShell();

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know that probably for many people this question is very stupid, but for a while I had given up on this project that was working so far. A few days ago when I wanted to restart it, I started it and this error happened and I don't understand why.
Using this piece of code:

```cs
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

It gives me this error:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

---

I put a try chatch in my code like this:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            try
            {
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                LoadApplication(new App());
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
            }
        }    #here the exception is raised And not above
```

Comment: look at the `InnerException` property for more detail on the root cause

Comment: I don't see anything because the exception, I noticed using debugging, is raised when closing the method: OnCreate of the MainActivity.cs method

Comment: @Timopek I don't understand your explanation for why you can't obtain this information.  `TargetInvocationException` is a wrapper around the actual exception.  This question is therefore unanswerable without it and will be closed.

Comment: Use a try/catch around the suspect code to catch the exception and examine it.  This is basic debugging

Comment: Yes sorry I thought you were in a class where I can't work. I noticed that I can write there, though. I will now provide to use the try and catch

Comment: I updated the question by putting the try catch but this is what I was able to find

Comment: I'd expect to see the full exception in the Visual Studio console, too (assuming you're running in the debugger). You can also break when TargetInvocationException is thrown and examine it that way...

Comment: This is the fole exchption:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. There are not anymore information

Comment: There are several places that should show the `InnerException`. **1)** VS Output Pane. **2)** Breakpoint on `{` line after `catch`, VS Locals pane, expand the exception to see its properties, `InnerException` property. **3)** menu Debug / Windows / Exception Settings / CHECK Common Language Runtime Exceptions. Then when run, it should stop on the line that causes the exception. In the Exception "popup" that appears in VS Source pane, click link "Copy Exception Details". Then "paste" the result into any text editor, or into the question. **4)** google `c# debug inner exceptions`.

Comment: put a breakpoint inside the catch and use the debugger to view the exception object.  Look at the **InnerException** property

Comment: Hello everyone. I've tried everything and the only information I could find, I tried try catch with debug going line by line, is this: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. I've tried any debug panel but that's the only info I get. The try has no result because the exception is raised when the method is closed and I cannot put a parenthesis in a try catch, and when the exception pops up the message that comes out is this.

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. and this is also the additional info.

Comment: Could you show us what is your appshell look like?